# How to make non-printable picture in a document?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I want to make a picture in the document to be shown when the document is opened but not visible in paper after printing (not to be printed).

I'm linking a hyperlink to an picture in the document so you can see the picture and link while the document is opened, but when printing I don't want this picture to be printed.

I want to share the document to others so that they are able to see and print the same as I do.

Comment: That's really not possible. If it appears on the monitor, it can be copied.

Comment: Is this just for your own (company) use? Or do you want to send the document to others, and control what their print will look like?

Comment: are you looking for _intentional use_ or for _malicious intent_? The latter is not possible.

Comment: @Arjan "Or do you want to send the document to others, and control what their print will look like?"  

that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Aganju What do you mean by _malicious intent_?

Comment: I meant: _Do you want to prohibit printing securely, against people that are trying to circumvent your limitation?_ Or just as a standard, that helps colleagues?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean MS Word, then you could use an image as page background 96 pixels/inch A4 size (21cm x 29.7cm). And then simply configure Word to not print background images (which is the default).

Then, if it's to be used as some template of a paper form to be filled in, you would need to format your text to go around it properly or use a transparent shape on top of it.

See [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/ms-word-hide-an-image-from-being-printed/3e7ccd4b-0c69-4cd2-9d55-1f4b956e00fc).